# DNX / .NET Core assembly versioning: 4.0.0 vs 4.0.10

Tags: c#, dnx, .net-core

I noticed that some base assemblies are available in 2 versions. For example, [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Concurrent/).

4.0.0 and 4.0.10 seem to be maintained simultaneously:

[image: nuget]

What is the reason behind this fragmentation?
How are these versions different, and which should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the difference between the `4.0.0`, `*.10` & `*.20` packages is what frameworks they target. Here is what they look like for the `System.Collections.Immutable` package.

`4.0.0`: net45+win8+wpa81
`4.0.10`: net46+uap10.0

Specifically, the difference between these two packages is that the `4.0.10` version implements `IReadOnlyCollection` and `IReadOnlyDictionary`.

As for the fragmentation, there are some internal mechanics of the .NET Framework that led them to use this versioning schema. Don't worry too much about the details.

Use the version that makes the most sense given the information above. If you're writing a library, I would encourage you to use the lowest possible version so that you're compatible with more technologies. If you're writing a .NET 4.6 or Universal Windows app, you might as well use the latest.